# Dynamic Expression Casting DateTime as timestamp

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, db2-400

When running a raw linq statement against entities with entity framework 5 - db2400 database, this where clause is rendered as good SQL and executes as needed:

```
where entity.Number == stringNumber && entity.EffectiveDate == effectiveDate
```

Rendered SQL Clause:

```
WHERE (Filter1.NUMBER = @p__linq__0) AND (Filter1.EFFECTIVE_DATE = @p__linq__1)}
```

However, when dynamically generating an expression with this same DateTime comparison, the SQL is sent to the DB2400 as a string casted timestamp.  And DB2 says, "I cannot compare a timestamp and a Date!" (since the column is of type Date on the table).

Rendered Expression:

```
Entity => ((Entity.Number == "somestring") And (Entity.EffectiveDate == 10/1/2012 12:00:00 AM))
```

Rendered SQL:

```
WHERE (('someString' = Extent1.NUMBER)) AND (CAST('2012-10-01 00:00:00.00000' AS timestamp) = Extent6.EFFECTIVE_DATE)}
```

How is this DateTime expression built?

```
Expression.Equal(Property, DateTime.Parse(someDateTime.ToString()));
```