# Regex replace for specific condition

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string like this:

> "(Extent2.pending_DLU > CAST('2015-05-26 00:00:00.00000' AS
>   timestamp))​   (Extent1.status_DLU > CAST('2015-05-26 00:00:00.00000'
>   AS timestamp)) and  (Extent1.RQST_SUBMT_TS = CAST('2015-05-26
>   00:00:00.00000' AS timestamp ) or (Extent2.WOstatus > CAST('2015-05-26
>   00:00:00.00000' AS timestamp))"

I want to replace 'timestamp' with 'date' except when the column is `RQST_SUBMT_TS`.

Expected output:

> "(Extent2.pending_DLU > CAST('2015-05-26 00:00:00.00000' AS
>   date))​(Extent1.status_DLU > CAST('2015-05-26 00:00:00.00000' AS
>   date)) and  (Extent1.RQST_SUBMT_TS = CAST('2015-05-26 00:00:00.00000'
>   AS timestamp ) or (Extent2.WOstatus > CAST('2015-05-26 00:00:00.00000'
>   AS date))"

I created the following regex but it is not correct:

```
 /timestamp\b!([A-Za-z0-9()\s]+.RQST_SUBMT_TS\s[<>=]?[<>=]\sCAST\(\'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{5}\'\sAS\stimestamp)+/g
```

Could anyone please help me figure out the correct regex pattern to do this?

**Edit** : To give some background. 
I am facing the same issue mentined here
[Dynamic Expression Casting DateTime as timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21048053/5892319?stw=2) .
As a workaround i am getting the query and trying to replace 'timestamp' with 'date' . but it has to be done only for columns with DATE datatypes.

Comment: Must this be done with regular expressions?

Comment: @Eminem i am  open for differnt approach too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tested this code**

```
 string Data = "(Extent2.pending_DLU > CAST('2015-05-26 00:00:00.00000' AS timestamp))​ (Extent1.status_DLU > CAST('2015-05-26 00:00:00.00000' AS timestamp)) and (Extent1.RQST_SUBMT_TS = CAST('2015-05-26 00:00:00.00000' AS timestamp ) or (Extent2.WOstatus > CAST('2015-05-26 00:00:00.00000' AS timestamp))";
 var pattern = @"timestamp|RQST_SUBMT_TS.*?timestamp";
 var cleanedUpValue = Regex.Replace(Data, pattern, m => m.Value.Length > "timestamp".Length ? m.Value : "date");
```

---

**Output**

`(Extent2.pending_DLU > CAST('2015-05-26 00:00:00.00000' AS date))​ (Extent1.status_DLU > CAST('2015-05-26 00:00:00.00000' AS date)) and (Extent1.RQST_SUBMT_TS = CAST('2015-05-26 00:00:00.00000' AS timestamp ) or (Extent2.WOstatus > CAST('2015-05-26 00:00:00.00000' AS date))`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
/\(([A-Za-z0-9()\s]+.RQST_SUBMT_TS\s[<>=]?[<>=]\sCAST\(\'\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{5}\'\sAS\stimestamp)+g
```

Replaced `timestamp\b!` with `\(`
Replaced `CAST(\'` with `CAST\(\'`

Answer (score 0):

The following simple regex matches timestamp in your example, but I'm not sure if it is flexible enough for you:

```
(?<!RQST_SUBMT_TS.{39})timestamp
```